# Cant open file upload dialog in ajax form in Opera

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, opera

I have a form that loads via ajax, something like this:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="trigger"></div>
    <div class="hide">
        <input type="file" />
    </div>
</form>

<style>
    #hide {
        position: relative;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

When you click on #trigger it triggers click on file input and it works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not in opera (v12.16).

Comment: Where is the trigger code?

Comment: its simple as:

$('#trigger').on('click', function(){
    $('.hide input[type=file]').trigger('click');
});

nothing fancy

Comment: 1- it's unrelated but hide is used as a class and in your style it's an ID #hide. 2-Opera 12 is quite an older version, therefore it might not as error forgiving as firefox or chrome. Try to give a unique ID, say #fileDialog to your input file and when #trigger is clicked, trigger the click event on that #fileDialog input directly. 3- does Opera console show any errors? 4- consider that an older browser versions might allow you to trigger a file upload event, I think due to security